# Section titles for documentclass beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, beamerposter

I am using the template available [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/gemini-poster-theme/nzpspqjryjhx) to make a poster.

Using `section` in the document doesn't display the section titles,

```
\section*{Equation 2:}
\subsection*{Number = 2}
\begin{equation*}
  X = CS = \frac{R}{8}\Delta G
\end{equation*}
```

Only the equation is displayed in the document.

Whereas while using documentclass `article` the section title appears,

```
documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \section*{Equation 2:}
    \subsection*{Number = 2}
    \begin{equation*}
      X = CS = \frac{R}{8}\Delta G
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions on how to display the section titles while using documentclass 'beamer` ?

Comment: I think, how sectional header in beamer show depends on the style. Have you tried to use a different theme?

Comment: Use `\frametitle{}`

Comment: @KurniawanPrihadi [This](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/gemini-poster-theme/nzpspqjryjhx) is the template that I am using .It uses `gemini` theme. Could you please suggest the other themes that I can try?

Comment: @MishraS I am not sure why the frame title has to be inserted. I have used one`\begin{frame}` and \end{frame}` for the whole  poster.Could you please explain?

Comment: Ok. Let me check

Comment: I think the rule for displaying section title on beamer is a little bit different than on article class. A section title on beamer will be displayed when you add a new frame. Gemini just uses a single frame for the whole document. Maybe you should add the section title manually as a block title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In beamer `sections` are structuring elements which encompasses multiple frames/pages. As a poster only uses a single frames, it is not appropriate to use sections there.

Your template uses `blocks` instead to structure the content:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[size=custom,width=120,height=72,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{gemini}
\usecolortheme{gemini}

\title{Some fancy title: followed by some more text}

\author{Alyssa P. Hacker \inst{1} \and Ben Bitdiddle \inst{2} \and Lem E. Tweakit \inst{2}}

\institute[shortinst]{\inst{1} Some Institute \samelineand \inst{2} Another Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{columns}[t]

\begin{column}{.3\textwidth}

  \begin{block}{Section title}
    content of the section
  \end{block}

\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```